# Git merge is successful but one file is not being merged

Tags: git

We have created a feature branch out of develop. And we sync that future branch with develop every week.

After syncing the feature branch with most recent develop we have noticed the one particular file is not being updated. The file is not updated with develop branch version.

We are merging develop into feature every time. Conflict will arise if there is any difference between files.

But why this particular file is not being merged?

Comment: I doubt the file wasn't merged. Either it hasn't been changed in the branches you're merging, or there was a conflict and someone resolved it by discarding the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to re-play the merge, on any clone of the repo :

```
# go back to the merge commit itself :
git checkout <sha1-of-merge-commit>
# if the current state of 'develop' is that merge commit,
# git checkout develop works fine too

# give a name to the previous states of 'develop' and 'feature' :
git branch tmp-develop HEAD^
git branch tmp-feature HEAD^2

# checkout tmp-develop, and merge tmp-feature
git checkout tmp-develop
git merge tmp-feature
```

This will allow you to see if :

- there actually was a conflict on this file (and someone or some script fixed that conflict manually),
- the merge actually results in taking the version from `feature` or from `develop`,
- the merge succeeds, and results in something else -- in which case : someone or some script ran an action on that file before pushing the merge commit